# Next failed to load SWC binary, what to do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I turn on SWR on my working computer crashes

```
(Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\srcProjects\frontend\node_modules\next\node_modules\@next\swc-win32-x64-msvc\next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node
at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1144:18)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
at loadNative (C:\srcProjects\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\swc\index.js:84:28)
at loadBindings (C:\srcProjects\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\swc\index.js:41:32)
at async Object.isWasm (C:\srcProjects\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\swc\index.js:146:20)
at async C:\srcProjects\frontend\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\loaders\next-swc-loader.js:62:178 {
code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
error - Failed to load SWC binary, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc)
```

I turn it on at home, everything is ok (both there and there Windows)

Comment: Can you try running `npm i @next/swc-win32-x64-msvc --no-save` ?